# Why Remote for Github is named "origin" instead of "github"

Tags: github, git-remote

I'm new to GIT and github and confused as to why the standard remote name is origin instead of github.

Why not just use "github" instead of "origin" for the remote name?

Comment: I apologize, I didn't mean to be a smart ass, though I did come across that way. All I was trying to say is that "why is this thing named this word" questions are all arbitrary. The answer is most always "just cause it is".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github is just a company that hosts git repositories. Git is a tool that can be used on with whatever repository host you want. There are alternatives to github, although github is certainly the most popular repository host.

Origin is the default name for a remote Git repository. This means what when you look up documentation online for how to use git commands and find something like `git push origin master`, it *just works* regardless of whether it's on Github, Bitbucket, or a self-hosted server. If this were not the case, all documentation would become more complex as it would  as it would need to tell users how to figure out what the remote is named by their repo hosting provider, then how to do the actual command.

Comment: i know what github is actually. my question was about the remote naming convention of origin vs something more specific like github. so when you review your list of remotes "git remote" you see "github" instead of the generic "origin".

Comment: Origin is just a default naming convention for referring to a remote Git repository. The point is that it is NOT github-specific. If it were, all generic git documentation that tells users how to do things that rely on the existence of a default name for this (ie: `git push origin master`) would become more complicated, as it would need to tell users how to figure out what the remote is named by their repo hosting provider, then how to do the actual command.

Comment: can you edit your answer and include your last comment? If you do then I can upvote it or set it as the answer. I appreciate the new details. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you also get `origin` as remote name when you just `git clone` a repository.